# Shorter ipdb output

Tags: python, debugging, ipdb

I'm new to ipdb and it looks great. But one thing is annoying. When an  error occurs the traceback is shown followed by 10 lines "If you suspect this ...". How can i get rid of this additional lines (disable/replace). They are always the same and consuming space without content.

```
If you suspect this is an IPython bug, please report it at:
    https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues
or send an email to the mailing list at ipython-dev@scipy.org

You can print a more detailed traceback right now with "%tb", or use "%debug"
to interactively debug it.

Extra-detailed tracebacks for bug-reporting purposes can be enabled via:
    %config Application.verbose_crash=True
```